# parametrized sql with multiple parameters

Tags: sql, dynamic, parameterized

I am missing something in my SQL query, could please someone advise how to do correct it? This is my SQL:

```
declare @numItems int;
declare @value1 int;
declare @value2 int;
declare @currentValue int;
declare @counter int;
declare @qry nvarchar(max)

set @value1 = 5;
set @value2 = 10;

set @numItems = 2
set @counter=0

WHILE (@counter < @numItems)
BEGIN
    set @qry = 'set @currentValue = @value' + cast(@counter+1 as nvarchar(max)) + ';'   
    exec sp_executesql @qry, N'@currentValue int OUTPUT', @currentValue OUTPUT

    print @currentValue

    set @counter = @counter + 1;
END
```

What I want is that @currentValue parameter gets values of @value1 and @value2 and prints them.
I'm not sure how to correctly declare parameters in the exec statement. I am using SQL Server 2005. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @numItems int;
declare @value1 int;
declare @value2 int;
declare @currentValue int;
declare @counter int;
declare @qry nvarchar(max)

set @value1 = 5;
set @value2 = 10;

set @numItems = 2
set @counter=0

WHILE (@counter < @numItems)
BEGIN
    set @qry = 'set @currentValue = @value' + cast(@counter+1 as nvarchar(max)) + ';'   
    exec sp_executesql @qry, 
                        N'@value1 int, @value2 int, @currentValue int OUTPUT', 
                        @value1=@value1,@value2=@value2, @currentValue = @currentValue OUTPUT

    print @currentValue

    set @counter = @counter + 1;
END
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. FYI @lekso. An Exec'd query haa it's own scope. It only sees items declared inside the sql being exec'd.

Comment: Thanks Martin, this is definitively an answer to my question. Is there any way not to hard code values @@value1 and @@value2 in the exec query, for instance if I had a large amount of '@@value..' parameters?

Comment: @Tony Hopkins, thank you too. I read about that just didn't really understand how to implement this. Just now I found an interesting article/post: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: @lekso - If you have an arbitrarily long list of values then stick them in a table variable then use a cursor to loop through the rows in the table variable. Just have `@value int, @currentValue int OUTPUT` in the parameters list and assign `@value` the current value fetched in from the cursor.

Comment: I thought about a table but particularly in my case it is better to stick to separate variables. I also have only 8 of them, so your solution would do the job. Thanks